# Why does gdata:::reorder.factor behave differently from stats:::reorder.default for integers and doubles?

Tags: r, namespaces, masking

This is a follow up to [Reordering factor gives different results, depending on which packages are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939516/reordering-factor-gives-different-results-depending-on-which-packages-are-loade), with another, related question.

[@Andrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602276/andrie)'s answer is the correct one and following [@David Lovell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1014385/david-lovell)'s comment, I am a third confused soul because of this.

In my case it was because I had loaded `ROCR`, which depends on `gplots`, which depends on `gdata`, and I hadn't even heard of `gdata`, to illustrate my ignorance, and therefore didn't think to search for it.

I've discovered another quirk, which made it even more difficult to work out in my case, and is the point of this question. Something about `gdata:::reorder.factor` handles integers and numerics differently. To illustrate:

```
library(gdata)
x <- factor(letters[1:6])
y <- c(1,4,3,5,6,2)
z <- c(1.1,2.4,1.3,2.5,2.6,1.2)
stats:::reorder.default(x, y, function(X)-X) #edbcfa - correct
stats:::reorder.default(x, z, function(X)-X) #edbcfa
stats:::reorder.default(x, -y)               #edbcfa
stats:::reorder.default(x, -z)               #edbcfa
gdata:::reorder.factor(x, y, function(X)-X)  #edbcfa
gdata:::reorder.factor(x, z, function(X)-X)  #bdeafc - weird
gdata:::reorder.factor(x, -y)                #abcdef - no reordering
gdata:::reorder.factor(x, -z)                #abcdef - no reordering
```

It's mostly the *bdeafc* that I'm interested in. It has got the bit before the decimal correct, in that the 2.x are before the 1.x, but the part after the decimal point is in normal order, not reverse order: x.1 before x.2 before x.3.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why this is happening:

Hm, this seems to be because `gdata:::reorder.factor` takes in an argument named `sort` which by default has value `mixedsort`. This `mixedsort` argument uses `mixedorder` function from package `gtools`. By loading `gtools` and doing `?mixedorder`, you can find out why this is happening:

> `?mixedorder`
>
> #### Order or Sort strings with embedded numbers **so that the numbers are in the correct order**:
>
> These functions sort or order character strings containing numbers so that the numbers are numerically sorted rather than sorted by character value. I.e. "Asprin 50mg" will come before "Asprin 100mg". In addition, case of character strings is ignored so that "a", will come before "B" and "C".

Also `?reorder.factor` clearly states this:

> `?gdata:::reorder.factor`
>
> If sort is provided (as it is by default): The new factor level names are generated by applying the supplied function to the existing factor level names. With sort=mixedsort the factor levels are sorted so that combined numeric and character strings are sorted in according to character rules on the character sections (including ignoring case), and the numeric rules for the numeric sections. See mixedsort for details.

---

### Solution:

You'll have to provide a value of NULL to `sort` argument so that `mixedsort` is not taken by default.

```
gdata:::reorder.factor(x, z, function(X)-X, sort=NULL)
# [1] a b c d e f
# Levels: e d b c f a
```

Alternatively, as @BenBolker points out under comments, you can provide "sort" argument as simply `sort`:

```
gdata:::reorder.factor(x, z, function(X)-X, sort=sort)
```

---

### On debugging:

For the future, `debugonce` is your friend for these sort of things. By doing

```
debugonce(gdata:::reorder.factor)
gdata:::reorder.factor(x, z, function(X)-X)
```

(and hitting enter and inspecting the output) you can find that the issue comes from the last few  lines that are being run:

```
else if (!missing(FUN)) 
    new.order <- names(sort(tapply(X, x, FUN, ...)))
```

For your data,

```
> X
# [1] 1.1 2.4 1.3 2.5 2.6 1.2

> x
# [1] a b c d e f
# Levels: a b c d e f
```

And, `tapply(...)` gives:

```
> tapply(X, x, FUN, ...)
#    a    b    c    d    e    f 
# -1.1 -2.4 -1.3 -2.5 -2.6 -1.2
```

Here, the "sort" should give:

```
> base:::sort(tapply(X, x, FUN, ...))
#    e    d    b    c    f    a 
# -2.6 -2.5 -2.4 -1.3 -1.2 -1.1
```

But it gives:

```
#   b    d    e    a    f    c 
# -2.4 -2.5 -2.6 -1.1 -1.2 -1.3
```

This is because the "sort" that's being called is not from base, which can be seen by typing "sort" from within the debugger:

```
> sort # from within the function call (using debugonce)
# function (x) 
# x[mixedorder(x)]
# <environment: namespace:gtools>
```

`mixedorder` is a function from package `gtools`. Since the command fetches the `names` and the sorting is wrong, the wrong order is being fetched. So basically the issue is that the `sort` that's being called is `mixedsort` and not `base:::sort`.

It's easy to verify this by installing `gtools` and doing:

```
require(gtools)
gtools:::mixedorder(c(-2.4, -2.5, -2.6))
# [1] 1 2 3

order(c(-2.4, -2.5, -2.6))
# [1] 3 2 1
```

Therefore, you'll have to provide `sort=NULL` to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: you can also use `sort=sort`

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive answer, which explains how to avoid the problem very well. Essentially, `mixedorder` is being called, which works differently to `base:::sort`. However, the docs you quoted says it should, "...sort or order character strings containing numbers so that the numbers are numerically sorted...". So the question remains why does `mixedsort` think this order, i.e., bdeafc is the correct numerical order?