# Function reorder in R and ordering values

Tags: r, sorting

I'm trying the following function:

```
stest <- data.frame(group=c("John", "Jane", "James"), mean=c(3, 5, 1))
transform(stest, group = reorder(group, mean))
```

And expect the output be ordered by `mean`. Instead, I get:

```
  group mean
1  John    3
2  Jane    5
3 James    1
```

That is, same order as in the original dataframe.

Do I miss something? How to order a data frame correctly by one of its numerical variables?

Recommendations around is about using `reorder`, but I can't make it work as expected. Can any loaded packages interfere?

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you're after, but is : stest[order(stest$mean),] would be sufficient ?

Comment: @Chargaff Yep, it returns the right order, but when I'm trying to use this dataframe in `ggplot`, `ggplot` still plots it in the previous order.

Comment: @BlueMagister from the OPs last comment it looks like it may actually be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5208679/1317221

Comment: @user1317221_G Agreed. I cannot change my close vote to that question, however - only retract the close vote altogether. At the least, the title is ambiguous enough to point to both questions.

Answer (score 5):

from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/reorder.default)

> reorder is a generic function. The "default" method treats its first argument as a categorical variable, and reorders its levels based on the values of a second variable, usually numeric.

Note : Reordering **levels**, not the values of the factor variable(`group` in your case).

Compare:

```
levels(stest$group)
[1] "James" "Jane"  "John"
```

with

```
>  reorder(stest$group, c(1,2,3))
[1] John  Jane  James
attr(,"scores")
James  Jane  John 
    3     2     1 
Levels: John Jane James
```

**EDIT 1**

From your comment:

*"@Chargaff Yep, it returns the right order, but when I'm trying to use this dataframe in ggplot, ggplot still plots it in the previous order."*

it seems you do actually want to reorder levels for a ggplot. I suggest you do:

```
stest$group <- reorder(stest$group, stest$mean)
```

**EDIT 2**

RE your last comment that the above line of code has "no effect". Clearly it does:

```
> stest$group
[1] John  Jane  James
Levels: James Jane John         # <-------------------------------
> stest$group <- reorder(stest$group, stest$mean)              # |
> stest$group                                                  # |
[1] John  Jane  James                                          # |
attr(,"scores")                                                # | DIFFERENT :)
James  Jane  John                                              # |
    1     5     3                                              # | 
Levels: James John Jane        # <--------------------------------
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand the difference. The docs says that it reorders the levels, so why Jane with `5` isn't on the top or bottom?

Comment: look at my example. your original levels are in the order `"James" "Jane"  "John" ` I changed them by `1,2,3` hence now the levels, *not the data in the columns* , are `John Jane James` . Perhaps you should read `?levels`

Comment: I've tried `levels(stest$group) <- reorder(stest$group, stest$mean)` on the initial data, and it returned the same results `"John"  "Jane"  "James"` of `levels(stest$group)`. Can you help me to clarify why this happens?

Comment: use `stest$group <- reorder(stest$group, stest$mean)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that has no effect. The result is identical to the initial data.

Comment: I have `Error in attr(, "scores") : argument 1 is empty` when try `attr(,"scores")`. Is some package involved?

Comment: ...............only paste the code infront of `>` . At  this point I give up.

Comment: I found my mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20335767/911945 . Thanks a lot for your clues. Wouldn't solve it without your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wanting the `order` function which returns an index, not `reorder` which is used to change the order of factor levels. This would do it.

```
> stest[order(stest$mean),]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found my mistake thanks to user1317221_G and others.

The correct code that would order my dataset is:

```
stest$group <- reorder(stest$group, stest$mean, FUN=identity)
```

While

```
stest$group <- reorder(stest$group, stest$mean)
```

didn't order my dataframe. Not sure why `FUN = mean` didn't work, but I had to specify `identity`.

Possible reason is this: [Reordering factor gives different results, depending on which packages are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939516/reordering-factor-gives-different-results-depending-on-which-packages-are-loade)

**UPDATE**

It's not enough to have the first line of code. `reorder` does not coerce the second argument to factors, thus final ordering may be incomplete (e.g., higher values below lower values in descending order).

Therefore, to be sure you have the right order:

```
stest$group <- reorder(stest$group, as.factor(stest$mean), FUN=identity)
```