# "Error in match.arg(what) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector" when trying to run the impute function in the below code

Tags: r, hmisc

I'm trying to `impute` the missing values with mean in a column in the dataset.
Using impute function available in `Hmisc` package

Have tried running several set of codes. In past I've used the piece of code & on same dataset, however, now it's not running.

```
impute(crime$average.ed,mean)
crime$average.ed<-as.numeric(impute(crime$average.ed, mean))
summary(crime)
```

The missing values in the variable `average.ed` must replaced with mean.
I keep getting error

> Error in match.arg(what) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

(BTW mean is 10.51)

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for what so ever!

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the solution to the problem by myself. A package named e1071 was causing a problem when using with package Hmisc. Both the packages have impute function and when used provided when both the packages are active, it won't run. So moral of the story use any one of the package.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Rohan is 100% spot on. Yet, I want to make a few additions for people stuck with the same problem.

**TL;DR:**
Replace in your code the references to impute with
`Hmisc::impute(matrix_to_operate_on, replacement_value)`

The `impute` arguments list can be found in this doc, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/4.4-1/topics/impute.

**For geeks:**
The fraudulent/unwanted `impute` function is the one defined in the library `e1071`, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-4/topics/impute.

**How to diagnose the problem?**
In R there is a introspection functionality called `body()`, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/body.
This will allow you to view the source of the actual function that you are invoking.

In the problematic case this would look like:

```
> body(impute)
{
    what <- match.arg(what)
    if (what == "median") {
        retval <- apply(x, 2, function(z) {
            z[is.na(z)] <- median(z, na.rm = TRUE)
            z
        })
    }
    else if (what == "mean") {
        retval <- apply(x, 2, function(z) {
            z[is.na(z)] <- mean(z, na.rm = TRUE)
            z
        })
    }
    retval
}
```

After investigating the body of the impute function, you are able to make a guess where is
the error above coming from, `Error in match.arg(what) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector`

Now you know the problem, so just reference the right function by prepending the correct library `Hmisc::` to the impute call.

**Good practises:**
To avoid such sticky situation in future, always prepend the library where the function is coming from. You never know if there aren't any other R functions which have "evil" twins.
[From [package] import [function] in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150870/from-package-import-function-in-r)