# Removing/de-registering a specific function from an R package

Tags: r, package, environment

I may not be using the terminology correctly here so please forgive me...

I have a case of one package 'overwriting' a function with the same name loaded by another package and thus changing the behavior (breaking) of a function.

The specific case:

```
X <- data.frame ( y = rnorm(100), x1 = rnorm(100), x2 = rnorm(100) )

library(CausalImpact)
a <- CausalImpact::CausalImpact( X, c(1,75), c(76, 100) ) # works

library(bfast) # imports quantmod which loads crappy version of as.zoo.data.frame

b <- CausalImpact::CausalImpact( X, c(1,75), c(76, 100) ) # Error
```

I know the error comes from two versions of the function `as.zoo.data.frame`. 
The problematic version is imported by bfast from the package 'quantmod' (see https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/168). Unfortunately their hotfix did not prevent this error. Super annoying.

I can hack around this specific problem, but I was **wondering if there is a general way to like 'de-register' this function** variant from the search path. Neither `detach` nor `unloadNamespace` remove the offending function (same behavior after). An explanation and similar problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939516/reordering-factor-gives-different-results-depending-on-which-packages-are-loade/10940237#10940237) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004018/how-can-a-non-imported-method-in-a-not-attached-package-be-found-by-calls-to-fun), but I wasn't able to find a general solution. For instance I'd rather just remove this function than clone and re-write `CausalImpact` to deal with this behavior.

Comment: The usual way to deal with this is to load the one with the version you want to use last so it's the first on the search path

Comment: If you are using this function only at one specific place instead of loading the library . you can use `::` i.e `CausalImpact::CausalImpact` or `bfast::CausalImpact`.

Comment: @alistaire Unfortunately that does not work in this case. This may partly be due to the fact that the error is generated by a dependency of one package (quantmod)

Comment: @RonakShah Sorry, clarified that CausalImpact is not a function in bfast and is thus not overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer that works, but is less preferable than de-registering a S3 method because it involves replacing the registered version in the S3 Methods table with the desired method:

```
library(CausalImpact)
library(bfast) 
assignInNamespace("as.zoo.data.frame", zoo:::as.zoo.data.frame, ns = asNamespace("zoo"))
```

based partially on @smingerson's suggestion in the comments

Answer (score 10):

From R 3.6.0 onwards, there is a new option called "conflicts.policy" to handle this within an established framework. For small issues like this, you can use the new arguments to `library()`. If you aren't yet to 3.6, the easiest solution might be to explicitly namespace CausalImpact when you need it, i.e. `CausalImpact::CausalImpact`. That's a mouthful, so you could do `causal_impact <- CausalImpact::CausalImpact` and use that alias.

```
# only attach select
library(dplyr, include.only = "select")
# exclude slice/arrange from being attached.
library(dplyr, exclude = c("slice", "arrange"))
```

`library(bfast, exclude = "CausalImpact")` should solve your problem.

Attach means that they are available for use without explicit prefixing with their package. In either of these cases, something like `dplyr::slice` would work just fine.

For more information, you can see `?library`. Also, the R-Core member Luke Tierney wrote a blog explaining how the conflicts.policy works. You can find that [here](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2019/03/19/managing-search-path-conflicts/)

Comment: thanks @smingerson. Unfortunately exclude isn't seeming to work in this case. If I try library(bfast, exclude = 'as.zoo.data.frame'), nothing changes because the offending function is actually from quantmod, a package that bfast loads. When I try to first load quantmod without this change: library(quantmod, exclude = 'as.zoo.data.frame') the function is still overwritten. I know this because R 6.0.1 gives me the message "Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
  method - as.zoo.data.frame; from - zoo. If I try to exclude another random function from quantmod, the exclude call works.

Comment: You could try defining the as.zoo.data.frame method within your script as defined in the zoo package. Kinda crazy someone would overwrite that... I don't think methods are typically exported using the same mechanism, so that could be why it failed.

Comment: Yeah, the quantmod version actually preceded the zoo version, strangely enough https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/168